# Using php switch statement to display an image url in an html table from a mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql, switch-statement

I have a MySQL table field which consists of a URL pointing towards an image.  I'm using php and want the image to display in a table along with the other fields.

I think I need to use the PHP Switch statement and reference either the Row('Name') or Field Ref Number to create the code. I have this working fine in classic-asp, but need to code this in php.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sometext,urlvalue,somemoretext FROM Table");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");

    // Table fields
    // sometext
    // urlvalue  an http image address such as http://www.example.com/image.jpg"
    // somemoretext

    $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr bgcolor='yellow' align='left'>";
            for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
                $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
                echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
            }
            echo "\n";

            // printing table rows
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";

                    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
                    // of $row to $cell variable
                    foreach($row as $cell)
                        switch $fields_num {
                            case "2":

                            // result cell looks like this ---->
                            // <td><a target='_blank'  href='http://www.example.com/image.jpg'><img src='http://http://www.example.com/image.jpg'></a></td>

                                echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='" . $cell ."'><img src='" . $cell ."'></a></td>";
                                break;
                            default:
                                echo "<td>$cell</td>";
                                echo "</tr>\n";
                        }
                        mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: I can provide three suggestions: 1. Instead of echoing, build a string, and echo it at the end 2. If you can clean up the source code, it would be easier to provide accurate help 3. Can you describe the actual problem you are having - i.e. what is that you think your output should be vs what you are actually getting.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: The parameter to `switch` has to be in parentheses: `switch ($fields_num) { ... }`

Comment: Please be more specific about your table structure and column names so that we can offer a clean answer for you.

Comment: @John do you know in advance which rows you are selecting in your query? or are you using `*` in the SELECT clause?  Just how variable is your project?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the columns that you are going to be accessing and you know which column is the url, then you can use the following `mysqli_`-based code block with a condition in the inner loop to check for the matching column name.

If you don't know the columns that you will be dealing with, you can use `filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` assuming you only have one url string in your resultset.  If you go for this second option, the one side effect on my code block is that you would have re-engineer the `<th>` portion.

I refuse to write answers using `mysql_` functions, so please take this chance to modernize your code.  I've included the connection declaration and basic error checking for your debugging convenience.  (Never display error messages on your public site.)

Untested Code:

```
$columns = ['sometext', 'urlvalue', 'somemoretext'];
if (!$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db")) {
    echo "Database Connect Error: " , $mysqli->connect_error;
} elseif (!$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `" . implode('`, `', $columns) . "` FROM `Table`")) {
    echo "Query Syntax Error: " , $mysqli->error;
    if (!$result->num_rows) {
        echo "No Rows Found";
    } else {
        echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr bgcolor='yellow' align='left'>";
                echo "<th>" , implode("</th><th>", $columns) , "</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
                        echo "<td>";
                            if ($col == 'urlvalue') {  // or if (filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
                                echo "<a target='_blank' href='$val'><img src='$val'></a>";
                            } else {
                                echo "$val";
                            }
                        echo "</td>";
                    }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not completely sure what you mean but rather than referencing the field number just reference the name.

```
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<table border='1'><tr bgcolor='yellow' align='left'>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<th>".$row['field-name']."</th>";
                echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='" . $row['field-name'] ."'><img src='" . $row['field-name'] ."'> 
                 </a> 
            </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
           echo "</table>";
        }
```

Comment: The location of your `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` is useless; `while` already has this effect.  In fact, your first `<tr>` NEEDS to be in the loop because right now your code is broken.  Please fix your tabbing.  You don't need `> 0`.

Comment: You are in no way implementing the column number check (`2`) that the OP is asking about.

Comment: he didn't ask see "I think I need to use the PHP Switch statement and reference either the Row('Name') or Field Ref Number to create the code" I am telling him to reference the name.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice considering how you  are acting here and saying you were reporting the last person.

Comment: I told them exactly why I flagged them -- that IS feedback.  Your answer is not correct.  Look at the structure of your `<tr>` tags.

Comment: My TR is in the loop

Comment: I looked at the edit history and my tr has always been in the loop

Comment: also see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select. for "The location of your if ($result->num_rows > 0) { is useless; "

Comment: ....no, not THAT `<tr>`, the other `<tr>` You are writing a broken table.  You have edited the if statement since my comment. (I will never refer anyone to w3schools for any content that can be found on php.net)

Comment: I copy and pasted from OP which has the two TRs

Comment: Then don't blindly copy-and-paste -- that is the downfall of computer programming.